# What is the differences of Nude and Naked

Tags: vocabulary

I know this is an awkward questions, but i really  confuse  this two, which one is use to refer completely  shirtless and which one is use to refer having a little clothes  on ( bra and underpant).

Comment: Both mean wearing no clothes at all.

Comment: You could use **undressed**, although this is ambiguous since it could also mean naked. The phrase **scantily clad** might be what you are looking for.

Comment: "Naked" is used more widely in metaphor, and in limited contexts such as: *he displayed naked aggression* or *with naked arms he snatched the object from the flames*. "Nude" is normally only used to describe a human being with absolutely no clothes" - it also has stronger artistic and sexual connotations.